# colinearity in stepwise regression

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, multicollinearity, stepwise-regression, validity

I would be very grateful if you can be so kind to clarify what may be wrong in the following steps and interpretation of the validity conditions of the stepwise regression.

I am afraid there is a mistake in the stepwise regression I did. Below are the results where I have doubts.

What should I do? Am I understanding something wrong? Do I need to choose a different regression?

Sorry, if these issues I am not understanding are basic, as I have some limited knowledge in regression modelling and analysis.

Data for this research was retrieved from the financial statements of companies from one only industry worldwide for the periods 2018, 2019 and 2020. The dependent variable is Profitability (Gross Profit Margin), and the independent ones are balance sheet items scaled by total assets and other financial ratios.

I run a stepwise regression for the 3 years data together with 2 dummies for years that were significant at 5%.
Then, I decided to split the samples into 3 samples (only data from one year in each sample) and did 3 cross section stepwise regressions.

I thought the stepwise regression would consider the correlation between the independent variables, but I am afraid it does not.

When I went to check the validity conditions of regressions for each year - 2018, 2019 and 2020 - which was found to be the best fit, I realized by looking at the Q-Q plots of the residuals that they were NOT random (and they should be random based on the preconditions for validity, is this right?)

Following, I checked the condition of multicollinearity.
When doing the correlation analysis with all the variables we found significant for the regression I surprisingly found that there was also correlation between the independent variables themselves.

I find this odd because when Looking at the collinearity diagnostics that came with the regression, they looked fine, as shown below. What is wrong here?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Following, I checked the condition of multicollinearity.
When doing the correlation analysis with all the variables we found significant for the regression I surprisingly found that there was also correlation between the independent variables themselves.

I find this odd because when Looking at the collinearity diagnostics that came with the regression, they looked fine, as shown below. What is wrong here?

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to use stepwise regression? It's a widely discouraged technique. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, other approaches will be more appropriate, so describing what you are aiming to do would be very helpful to help people recommend something better instead.

Comment: Thank you! Assuming that stepwise is appropriate for this analysis, I would like to understad how to do the interpretation of these results, and if am I wrong in my analysis. I would be very thankfull for any possible help

Comment: Why is stepwise discouraged?

Comment: There's really no situation where stepwise is appropriate. See many answers on the site, but it's no good for getting a small interpretable model (estimates, standard errors, p-values [cf. all the problems with post-model-selection inference] and terms selected to be included tend to be pretty wrong) and it's not good for creating a good prediction model. It's also pretty unstable: small changes in the data often make a big difference to the outcome (as you can see by bootstrapping your data and doing stepwise for each bootstrap sample).

Comment: For instance, a previous question about stepwise regression had multiple high-reputation members post answers discouraging the method. Then the OP posted a self-answer explaining why stepwise was wonderful. The answers discouraging stepwise regression all have many upvotes, while the self-answer encouraging stepwise regression is voted -57.

Comment: Thank you for your help. How did stepwise idea originate? Do you have any reference about its merit, when first announced to every body?

Comment: How can collinearity diagnosys be interpreted in stepwise regression?